# What is simplest way to filter blanks or nulls in Tabulator?

Tags: filter, tabulator

I have a requirement to filter out blank cells OR non-blank cells for a given column.  I could imagine a custom header formatter function that would add a control in the header to do this, but I would need to write a lot of code for this, right?  Both the headerFilter and the function would take significant custom coding. Am I over-thinking this problem? even if there is nothing built in to tabulator, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: JSfiddle ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what you are looking to filter.

If you want to filter out rows if the value of a certain property is empty then you can use a filter function (in this case im using the age field):

```
table.setFilter(function(data){
    return !!data.age;
});
```

Comment: that answers my question.  nothing already set up, I would need to create a button with a setFilter function

Comment: I would like for users to be able to enter a space in the header filter field and that would act to filter the rows whose column is either empty string, null, or undefined. No idea how to do that without creating a new UI control of some sort instead